# My app crash, reason 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I am using 2 tableview. I am using these two tables using tag. In Parent TableView there are 3 cell. and another table is added in the 3rd cell of Parent table. I double check whole code but I can't find error. However I getting this error and I am confused as to why? I don't know where is the issue. My app is crash. Here is my Crashi code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {   
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
        switch (tableView.tag)
        {
            case kTagBaseTableView:
            {
                if (indexPath.row == 0)
                {
                    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

                    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

                    if (cell == nil) {
                        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
                    }
                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
                    //return cell;
                }
                if (indexPath.row == 1)
                {
                    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell1";

                    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

                    if (cell == nil) {
                        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
                    }
                    self.scrollView1 = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
                    self.customStoryboardPageControl = (TAPageControl *)[cell viewWithTag:7];

                    self.scrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, cell.frame.size.height+55)];
                    [self.scrollView1 setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];

                    self.scrollView1.delegate = self;

                    self.customStoryboardPageControl = [[TAPageControl alloc] init];
                    self.customStoryboardPageControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, tableView.frame.size.width, 30);

                    self.customStoryboardPageControl.numberOfPages = self.imagesData.count;

                    [[cell contentView] addSubview:self.scrollView1];
                    [[cell contentView] addSubview:self.customStoryboardPageControl];

                    [self setupScrollViewImages];

                    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
                    //return cell;
                }
            }
            case kTagInnerTableView:
            {
                ORGContainerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ORGContainerCell"];
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                [cell setCollectionData:self.sampleData];
                [cell setCollectionImage:self.sampleImage];
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Horizontal TableView";
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                //return cell;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: have you check your table tag. if its called in both case.

Comment: Yes. I double checked My table tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final working code.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell1";
    static NSString *ORGContainerCellID1 = @"ORGContainerCell1";
    static NSString *ORGContainerCellID2 = @"ORGContainerCell2";
    static NSString *ORGContainerCellID3 = @"ORGContainerCell3";

    if (indexPath.section ==0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell; //= [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
            }
            btnSignIn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            lblUserName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:999];

            NSUserDefaults *defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            if ([defaults boolForKey:@"hasUserLoggedIn"])
            {
                btnSignIn.hidden = TRUE;
                lblUserName.hidden = FALSE;
                lblUserName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello,%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userName"]];
            }
            else
            {
                btnSignIn.hidden = FALSE;
                lblUserName.hidden = TRUE;
            }
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
             cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
            }
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10000, 0, 0);
            self.scrollView1 = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
            self.customStoryboardPageControl = (TAPageControl *)[cell viewWithTag:7];
            self.scrollView1.delegate = self;


            self.customStoryboardPageControl.numberOfPages = arrBannerData.count;

            [[cell contentView] addSubview:self.scrollView1];

            [self setupScrollViewImages];
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            ORGContainerCell *cell = [[ORGContainerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ORGContainerCellID1];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[ORGContainerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ORGContainerCellID1] ;
            }
            [cell setCollectionData1:self.arrProductName];
            [cell setCollectionImage1:self.arrProductImage];
            [cell setCollectionPrice1:arrProductPrice];
            [cell setCollectionHeader1:arrHeaderTitle];

            return  cell;
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            ORGContainerCell *cell = [[ORGContainerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ORGContainerCellID2];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[ORGContainerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ORGContainerCellID2] ;
            }
            [cell setCollectionData1:self.arrProductName1];
            [cell setCollectionImage1:self.arrProductImage1];
            [cell setCollectionPrice1:self.arrProductPrice1];
            [cell setCollectionHeader1:self.arrHeaderTitl1];

            return  cell;
        }
        else
        {
            ORGContainerCell *cell = [[ORGContainerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ORGContainerCellID3];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[ORGContainerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ORGContainerCellID3] ;
            }
            [cell setCollectionData1:self.arrProductName2];
            [cell setCollectionImage1:self.arrProductImage2];
            [cell setCollectionPrice1:self.arrProductPrice2];
            [cell setCollectionHeader1:self.arrHeaderTitl2];
            return  cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `ORGContainerCell *cell =`, you should use `cell =`

Comment: Nick Answer solve my Crash Issue  But my Inner table not load.

Comment: Better yet, rename it like `ORGContainerCell *containerCell` (since some methods need to be called on it), then do `cell = containerCell;`.

Comment: @MihirOza Why are you using two tableviews?

Comment: In sub table view I add third party horizontal scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `UITableViewCell *cell = nil;`

try `UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];`

Comment: Thanks . Solve My Crash Issue. But my Inner table not load. Help me to solve this.

Comment: for that issue try @Bannings solution.

Comment: shall I remove * sign ?

Comment: it's not working .Because ORGContainerCell isthird party cell.

Comment: ORGContainerCell not initialize return nil.

Comment: well you should check if it acutally is null, create new one

Answer (score 0):

The error message already tells you: sometimes, you are not returning an `UITableViewCell` object.

Add a safeguard like this:

```
return cell ?: [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

(the non-standard `?:` operator returns the left side if it's "true" [non-nil] or the right side otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

EDITED :

In your case `kTagInnerTableView`, You have taken a new object of your `ORGContainerCell`, So you can return that local object of the `ORGContainerCell` from that `case` of your `switch-case`.

Just use initially declared object like

```
case kTagInnerTableView:
            {
            ORGContainerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ORGContainerCell"];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            [cell setCollectionData:self.sampleData];
            [cell setCollectionImage:self.sampleImage];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Horizontal TableView";
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            return cell;                
            }
```

Comment: no I can't add like this. Because collectiondata and collectionimage method not call using this code.

Comment: if I uncomment the return cell. My App crash.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. Will you please Explain.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 rows in parent table view, but you created cells only for two of them. You should write creating cell code for third condition in first case block

```
else if (indexPath.row == 2)
```

and create your second table view inside it.